# Searching a Child Control

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I am using coded ui test with my windows store app.

My control hierarchy is :

UIPearsonPOCCommonViewFlipViewItem (XAMLFlipViewItem - > UIWebViewPane (XAMLWebViewPane) - > Rest of the content.

For rest of the child controls, there is no specific automation id or unique names and they look like html control for e.g. refer the image appended.

I want to iterate over the children of UIWebViewPane and reach to child DIV which is having the innerText.

I am relatively very new to coded ui test. I am unable to iterate over the children of UIWebViewPane(XAMLWebViewPane)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the child control's inner text is unique, you could always search on that using the parent control in the definition.  Ex:

```
public HtmlControl child()
{
    HtmlControl parent = new HtmlControl(browser);
    parent.SearchProperties["id"] = "[my id]";

    HtmlControl child = new HtmlControl(parent);
    child.SearchProperties["innerText"] = "[the inner text]";
    return child;
}
```

If you truly want to iterate through, then you'll have to crawl the structure using the .GetParent() and .GetChildren() methods of the UITestControl class.

```
public HtmlControl child()
{
    //First, we create an empty HtmlControl to return.
    HtmlControl result = new HtmlControl()

    //Specify the parent and get a collection of the children (this only goes one level, 
    //   so if you have to go deeper, you'll have to nest your foreach loops and get
    //   children of the children, etc.
    HtmlControl parent = new HtmlControl(browser);
    parent.SearchProperties["id"] = "[my id]";
    UITestControlCollection children = parent.GetChildren();

    foreach (UITestControl child in children)
    {
        // If the child has the text you're looking for, then assign it to the result
        // object and break the loop.
        if (child.GetProperty("InnerText").ToString().Equals(searchTerm))
        {
            result = (HtmlControl)child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Personally, I'd try the first option.  Your best bet, though, is to ask (politely) for the developer to add some unique and static tags to the HTML.